# Is $('.foo').eq(0) faster than $('.foo')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Suppose I have a huge list of elements with a structure like:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="meta"></div>
    <div class="..."></div>
    ...
</div><!-- .item -->
```

I've already found an element and now I have to find, let's say, a '.body'. What code will work faster:

```
$(el).find('.body')
```

or

```
$(el).find('.body').eq(0)
```

In other words, will jQuery stop on the first found element or will it loop through all the elements first and only then it will return an element with a chosen index?

Comment: $(el).find('.body:first') would logically be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example will always be slower, because it only calls an additional method on a jQuery object that contains all the elements matching `.body`.

The fastest way to get the first matching element is probably the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$(el).find(".body:first")
```

You could also spare one method call by using the `context` argument to [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), **but [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/to-eq-or-not-to-eq) reveal that's actually slower**:

```
$(".body:first", el)  // Slower, don't do that.
```

Comment: `:first` is pretty insignificant. It's useful but I wouldn't add it JUST for speed improvements.

Comment: Ok so I added `$(el).find(".body:first")` to the benchmark and Matt is right. out of 5 runs, it was fastest twice, 2nd place 3 times. http://jsperf.com/to-eq-or-not-to-eq

Comment: `$(".body:first", el)` is about 70% the speed of `$(el).find('.body')` consistently according to that benchmark in my previous comment. Keep in mind JQuery uses `getElementsByClassName` very intelligently and adding any pseudo-selectors to the selector string (I believe) forces extra traversal calculations.

Comment: You're both right, `find()` is fastest. Answer edited accordingly, thanks for the benchmark :)

Comment: FYI: The proprietary `:first` selector isn't only applied to the first element. It's a function that runs once for each element, so if 100 elements were matched by the main part of the selector, then the function will run 100 times. I'm guessing there are some performance improvements in that benchmark due to the fact that `:first` will *break* `querySelectorAll`, so I'm guessing `getElementsByClassName` is used instead, which is generally faster than `qsa`.

Comment: ...And the context parameter *adds* a function call instead of sparing one as compared to `$(el).find(...` because it calls the `$` function a second time, with `.find()`. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L170-174

Comment: @patrick, thank you for your insight. I'll be sure to remember that :)

Answer (score 6):

This question is ridiculous. "Is it faster if I add another function or if I leave it out of the equation?" is basically what you're asking:

`$(el).find('.body')` is about 6-7 times faster: http://jsperf.com/to-eq-or-not-to-eq

Answer (score 1):

`.eq(0)` is a method call on the object returned by `$(el).find('.body')`. It can't be faster then `$(el).find('.body')` alone.

Answer (score 0):

They will nearly same as as `.eq('0')` is called on the **result** of `find('.body')`. The second one is *never* faster.

Answer (score 0):

`$(el).find('.body:first')` or `$(el).find('.body.eq(0)')` would logically be faster, because (at least) it does execute less function calls